# How to Create a TemplateRef in a Service

Tags: angular

I have a global dialog/modal service that accepts a TemplateRef and properly renders this view in the dialog when I construct it. This works perfectly if I trigger this dialog from a component where I can reference a TemplateRef from my components DOM with `<ng-template>`. However, I need to trigger this dialog from my GlobalErrorHandler service and dynamically create the TemplateRef programmatically in the service, which then I can take this TemplateRef and pass it to the dialog service to be rendered.

I have had no luck with this at all and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a snippet of my latest attempt:

```
      const RENDERER = this._rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
      const CONTEXT = RENDERER.createElement('h1');
      CONTEXT.innerHTML = 'Hi I am a dialog';
      const DIALOG = this.injector.get(GlobalDialogService);
      let DIALOG_CONTENT: TemplateRef<any>;
      let view = DIALOG_CONTENT.createEmbeddedView(CONTEXT);
      DIALOG.instantiateDialog(new GlobalDialogSettings(view.context, 'Test Header', false));
      DIALOG.dialogVisiblityChange.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((isVisible: boolean): void => {
        if (!isVisible) {
          // do some stuff here
        }
      });
```